# Angular Dynamically load modules based on API response

Tags: angular, es6-modules, webpack-module-federation

Is it possible to lazy-loading modules, but without having a static declaration for them in the Angular application?
Currently each module is declared in the `RoutingModule`

```
{
  path: 'path-one',
  loadChildren: () => import('./components/PathOne').then(m => m.PathOneModule)
},
```

The desired outcome is to remove this static declaration and simply load the module dynamically based on an API response, similar like an ECMAScript module import.

```
async loadModule(moduleName: string): Promise<any> {
  const module = await import(`./components/${moduleName}`);
  if(!module) throw new Error('No module found!')
  return module;
}
```

As side note, this modules have multiple components inside of them and dependencies.

Comment: But how would the treeshaker know what bundles/chunks need to be expelled?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that in Angular, I think you have two options:

- Using [Webpack Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/), by separating the desired modules as federated modules. See this tutorial to know how to implement it in Angular:
  https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/tutorial/tutorial.md
- Using the ECMAScript dynamic `import()` function as follows:

*Assuming the `moduleName` is `A`, `B`, or `C`.*

`./components/index.ts`

```js
export default {
  exposes: {
    A: () => import('./a.module.ts'),
    B: () => import('./b.module.ts'),
    C: () => import('./c.module.ts'),
  },
};
```

Then in other modules:

```js
async function loadModule(moduleName: string): Promise<any> {
  return import(`./components`).then((m) => {
    const loadModule = m.default.exposes[moduleName];

    if (!loadModule) throw new Error('No module found!');

    return loadModule();
  });
}
```

This keeps each module in a separate chunk, and only loads the desired one once needed.